# Yup schema email reset password field validations with formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

I am using formic for the forms , So Here is my HTML

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={css.loginForm}>
            <Input
              variant='standard'
              textAlign='center'
              placeholder='Password'
              id='password'
              name='password'
              type='password'
              value={values.password}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              autoFocus
              error={errors.password && touched.password}
            />
            <Input
              variant='standard'
              textAlign='center'
              placeholder='Repeat Password'
              id='repeatPassword'
              name='repeatPassword'
              type='password'
              value={values.repeatPassword}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              autoFocus
              error={errors.repeatPassword && touched.repeatPassword}
            />
  {errors.repeatPassword ? (
         <div>{errors.repeatPassword}</div>
       ) : null}
         <Button
          variant='primary'
          theme='light'
          type='submit'
          disabled={!!errors.password || !!errors.repeatPassword}>
          <Typography variant='h1'>Reset Password</Typography>
        </Button>
    </form>
```

So Here now, I am using the validations like :

```
 validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
    repeatPassword: Yup.string()
    .required('')
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
  }),
```

Here , the conditions which gets failed are :

1. if the repeatpassword field is not filled then also the button gets enabled
2. I just wanted to show the message of the passwords must match including the conditions of both passwords needs to be matched and both fields are required .

Here,with these validation above things does not work

can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Because you validate `repeatPassword` with message is the empty string `''`. So if this field not filled `errors.repeatPassword` is `''` and `disabled` of button is `false`
2. Update your code like this:

   ```
   validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
     password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
     repeatPassword: Yup.string()
       .required('Required')
       .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
   }),
   ```

`{errors.repeatPassword !== "Required" && <div>{errors.repeatPassword}</div>}`